# Yahoo finance api not working

Tags: yahoo-finance

I am using yahoo finance api. Before 2-3 days it's stop working and giving the result 'redirect'.

I am using the following request,
URL: 'http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/^OMX,^gspc/quote?format=json&view=detail'

If anyone having any idea about the same please share any link or view.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem too. I fix it by using yahoo YQL, but it looks like not as good as using yahoo web service.

Comment: Hi Sabit,

Thank you for the reply.
Have you any idea about, how to use YQL for OMX and S&P.

Comment: I am not able to find the symbol for the OMX and S&P in YQL.

Comment: You can use this YQL url : https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22^OMX%22,%22^GSPC%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=

Comment: For more detail about YQL, go to this https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/ . Btw, there is lack on YQL. For example it not return value for ^DJI stock where yahoo web service can do. And i get report sometimes it show different value when you request multiple stock (MSFT, GOOG, etc) and request singlet stock (only MSFT for example)

Comment: Hi Sabit,

Yes, I used the YQL for the OMX and S&P it's give the different values.
I also checked the 'https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/' it's not working now.

Thank you for the reply.